# Docker + Laravel issue - "ViewException"

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, nginx

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

default.conf:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 index index.php index.html;
 server_name localhost;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 root /var/www/html/public;


 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }


 location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass php:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
 }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

.env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laraone
APP_ENV="local"
APP_KEY=base64:gw3VfvtH3/S/iYRWp0q8MsMB7LPthzkwoPHhJZhFF+o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8080

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laraone
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

MAIL_SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs"

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=
MAILGUN_SECRET=
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT="api.mailgun.net"

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I'm trying to run laravel application and I can tell for sure that database is working properly, .env file configuration is correct and application installation goes successfully (installation does database connection and creates all necessary tables correctly with correct default data inside them)

App works perfectly outside Docker container on Windows machine, problem emerges inside Docker container . My Docker uses linux containers. After reading laravel.log I see that ViewException gets thrown and none of the view files are loaded inside browser (instead I get 404 on homepage, on login page I get the exception which can be seen on screenshot below)

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClLrm.png)

I guess that app doesn't resolve correct path for view files and my question is if anyone here knows what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Adding the .env file can be helpful here, The .env file that works with `php artisan serve` is not exactly the same one that works with docker (as db config should be changed)

Comment: @SirNarsh My bad, I had just updated the question and added the .env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short**

Update DB_HOST in .env

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

**More about that**

In your .env file the hostname for your database is localhost

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

The reason it's working locally is because you exposed 3306 from docker to the host machine 3306

But both containers can access each other in internal docker network by using their docker hostname which is `mysql` based on your docker-compose file

Another solution but I don't recommend it  (Because since the mysql is already in the same stack no need to connect to host then go back to the mysql container since containers can access each other directly without using port exposed on host, and you can actually stop exposing this port later and it'll still work between the two containers)

```
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Comment: DB_HOST=mysql solution doesn't work for me, I get the following error:
`PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ")`
But the second solution works for me, thank you for the help you provided!

Answer (score 0):

add

```
    depends_on:
        - mysql
```

for php container section.
solution

```
php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```